# How to parse a nested JSON response to a list of Java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, pojo

I am looking to parse a response with nested JSON data into a list of Java objects. The JSON response is in the below format.

```
{
  "IsSuccess": true,
  "TotalCount": 250,
  "Response": [
    {
      "Name": "Afghanistan",
      "CurrencyCode": "AFN",
      "CurrencyName": "Afghan afghani"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Afghanistan",
      "CurrencyCode": "AFN",
      "CurrencyName": "Afghan afghani"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Afghanistan",
      "CurrencyCode": "AFN",
      "CurrencyName": "Afghan afghani"
    }
   ]
}
```

I have the corresponding Country class created for parsing as POJO. I'm using Jackson to parse the data.

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget t = c.target("http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries");
        Response r = t.request().get();
        String s = r.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(s);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Country> myObjects = mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<List<Country>>(){});
            System.out.println(myObjects.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The actual list of countries is withing the "Response" in the JSON String. How would I retrieve the contents under Response and then parse it as a list of countries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: What you get is a Response, which contains a List<Country>. But you try to parse this Response as a List<Country>. So that can' work. Parse the response as a Response, and it will work fine. Then get the list of countries out of the parsed Response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what Client API you are using that cannot simply provide entity of desired type. Most clients should have utility methods to do such conversion. Anyways, here's a way you can achieve what you want:

```
final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
final ArrayNode responseArray = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("Response");
//UPDATED to use convertValue()
final List<Country> countries = mapper.convertValue(responseArray, new TypeReference<List<Country>>(){});
```

Country.class

```
 class Country {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("CurrencyCode")
    public String currencyCode;
    @JsonProperty("CurrencyName")
    public String currencyName;
 }
```